# com.mongodb.MongoSocketException Name or service not known - for a secondary host

Tags: mongodb, replication

I am connecting to mongodb cluster with connection string. On updating an entity, mongodb throws the  below exception:

> org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: : Name or service not known; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: : Name or service not known

Host printed in error is a secondary host. Why is mongo client trying to connect to secondary host?

Few more related questions:

- In a replicaset, how does mongo client know the primary node to
  connect to?
- If ***write concern*** is ***majority***, will writes be rolled back
  on primary if primary host is healthy but total majority of nodes in
  cluster are down and don't acknowledge writes

Comment: How does your connection string look like? I think with `{writeConcern: {w: 'mojority'}}` the change is even not written to primary when majority is not available.

Comment: connection string is the set of hosts separated by semi colon. Example: host1:port;host2port2;

Comment: You need to add the replica set, see [Connection String URI Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/), Hosts are separated by comma, not semi colon.